# How to transmit CAN signals wirelessly without line of sight (LOS)

Tags: wireless, can, transmission

I have a scenario where I have an [OBD-II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD2#OBD-II) interface transmitting data via CAN across six wires to a display. I will have power on either side of the wires, but I cannot assume that the wires will have LOS (cable will be tucked away, so [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) isn't an option). I would essentially like to cut the wires, and transmit the data wirelessly between the two ends.

I have done a little reasearch and found these [encoders/decoders](http://www.holtek.com/english/products/encoder_decoder.htm).

These encoders/decoders will not transmit data. Apparently they just litterally encode/decode wired signals. But as little knowledge as I have on this topic, I'm not sure if they will accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: What's the justification of going wireless? There doesn't appear to be any?

Comment: Mostly aesthetic reasons, not needing to run wires all over the car, etc.. Also, it is potentially useful to use this display/tool while under the hood of a car. You would either need two (vendor specific) connection wires, or one wire that wasn't tucked into the dashboard/hidden.

Comment: The items you have linked are actually encoders/decoders - they still need wires to communicate serially with each other - they are not wireless.

Comment: Why don't you google wireless can transceivers?

Comment: I did google, just not correctly apparently. I found some things that may work, but I don't know enough about CAN signals. Would something like this do the trick:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12031

Comment: @Ryan that wouldn't work. I think there are CANBUS to Wireless Gateways products, but I expect they'll be pricey.

Comment: Meeting the hardware/sync requirements for CAN bus at either end of the link is the bigger of your worries I would think. If you don't know much about CAN bus then you might be opening a can of worms using some transceivers. I'm no expert on CAN so I'm backing out of the advising on this.

Comment: http://www.canbus-solutions.com/Products/RM/WirelessCanInterfaces/CANlinkBluetooth.aspx

Comment: @kenny I think you're correct, those gateway products are a bit over my needs. Some standalone transceiver from somewhere like sparkfun or jameco would be ideal. What specifically about the one I linked wouldn't work?

Comment: It doesn't interface to the CANBUS, you could build a micro to build a Gateway to a wireless interface like that, but that seems like more work than buying an expensive gateway.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ODBII connectors on eBay from China that have bluetooth built in to them. I'd use one of those.